# How to use the 'shortest' argument with ffmpeg-python

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm using [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) for my first time. I'm trying to use the `shortest=1` argument in `ffmpeg.output()`, but my program keeps giving me errors when I use it.

I want to replace the audio from `foo.mp4` with the audio from `bar.webm`, while keeping the visuals of `foo.mp4`. I got this working, but the problem is that `ffmpeg.concat` by default keeps playing the audio from `bar.webm` while the visuals from `foo.mp4` have stopped playing. According to [this FFmpeg docs page](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat), this is the intended behaviour:
"The concat filter will use the duration of the longest stream in each segment (except the last one), and if necessary pad shorter audio streams with silence."

I want the output video to stop when the visuals stop playing, so I want it to cut off the audio, but I can't get it to work. That page also states that I should be able to add `shortest` as an argument to get my desired result: "If set to 1, force the output to terminate when the shortest input terminates. Default value is 0." I can't get it to work, though. The second from the bottom line from the block of code below contains `shortest=1`, which I'd expect to work, but I get this error instead:

`[NULL @ 000001d50dfdea80] Unable to find a suitable output format for '1'` and `1: Invalid argument`

Using `shortestfoo` instead gives me this error, as expected:

`Unrecognized option 'shortestfoo'.` and `Error splitting the argument list: Option not found`

This tells me that the `shortest` argument was a possible argument, but that the `1` value that I assign to it is wrong. Setting it to `None` my program runs, but the audio still won't be cut off with this set to `None`, of course.

What value for `shortest` should I use here? Am I correct in assessing that I'm just using the wrong value for `shortest`? Many thanks!

Edit: Tried using `True` instead of 1. Tried using `**{'shortest': 1}` and `**{'shortest': True}`. These also didn't work.

```
import ffmpeg

input_video_name = 'foo'
input_video_extension = '.mp4'

input_audio_name = 'bar'
input_audio_extension = '.webm'

input_video = ffmpeg.input('input videos/' + input_video_name + input_video_extension)
input_audio = ffmpeg.input('input audio/'+ input_audio_name + input_audio_extension)

stream = ffmpeg.concat(input_video, input_audio, v=1, a=1)

stream = ffmpeg.output(stream, 'output videos/' + input_video_name + '.mp4', shortest=1)
ffmpeg.run(stream)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Found the answer**: [This person](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/issues/371#issuecomment-630904841) provided a solution to my problem. I don't know why this *does* work, so what I was missing in my original code, though:

```
video_part = ffmpeg.input('video.mp4')
audio_part = ffmpeg.input('audio.mp3')
(
    ffmpeg
    .output(audio_part.audio, video_part.video, 'output-video.mp4', shortest=None, vcodec='copy')
    .run()

)
```

Comment: This works because including 'shortest' adds 'shortest' to the dictionary of arguments for output(). The awkward part is that --shortest doesn't have a value in an ffmpeg command so it doesn't have one in the python interface either, hence shortest=None.